# Why Kinetic energy of Gas molecules independent of Mass?

Tags: kinetic-theory

By Kinetic Theory of Gas,

$K.E = \frac32 RT$ (i.e it is independent of mass of the gas)

Its proof is as follows:

We know , $P = \frac13 D\cdot v^2$ (where $D$ is mass density and $v$ is average of the squared velocity  of molecules)

Multiply both sides by $V$(Volume)
$$
PV = \frac13 Mv^2
$$
Multiply and divide by $2$ in the rhs of the equation
$$
PV= \frac23 × \frac12 Mv²
$$
$$
PV= \frac23 × K.E   ~~~~~~~~[1]
$$
$$
RT= \frac23 × K.E
$$
$$
K.E = \frac32 RT 
$$

But in [$1$] we used that $\frac12 Mv^2= K.E$ (i.e $K.E$ as a function of Mass).
In the end we got $K.E= \frac32 RT$ (i.e $K.E$ is independent of Mass)

Please explain  how $K.E$ of gases is independent of Mass

Comment: Dupe-voters, here's your target: [Kinetic Energy - dependence of mass](//physics.stackexchange.com/q/468259)

Comment: @nitsua60 Unfortunately no one of the answers  there could be considered an explanation.

Comment: Doesn't R include molar mass, i.e., aren't the units proportional to kg/mole?

Answer (score 1):

Because *relative change* in the number of microstates with energy does not depend on mass.

That is what thermal equilibrium is: when $\frac{1}{\Omega} \frac{{\rm d}\Omega}{{\rm d}E}$ is equal for two systems. Then their temperatures are the same.

So the number of microstates $\Omega$ att a certain energy depends on mass, but not the logarithmic derivative with respect to energy.